# User is not able to log in after some time

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc along with SQL server. An user of my application created a username like "abcd efgh", with space between the user name. it worked for some time and now it stopped working. I checked that user is entering the correct data. This happened even user did not have a space in it. I set up the membership database using Aspnet_regsql.exe.

Any help in trouble shooting this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are not parsing/modifying the username or password before giving it to Membership?

Why don't you set a breakpoint in your Controller Action and see what username and password are at that point?

Comment: It gives me the error "The username or password provided is incorrect.". When I check in the database, both are proper.

Comment: I checked the user name and password. Everything was already. And I checked in the aspnet_Membership table for this user. I found that IsLockedOut is set to 1 for some reason. I changed this to 0 and it started working.